# UWP Desktop Bridge & Local App Data virtualized folder location

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I am in the process of converting a Win32 app (Zoom Player) to the UWP AppX model using the "*Desktop Bridge*" conversion tool.

Under the folder model introduced in Windows VISTA, the application's files that do not require create/write access are installed under the "**Program Files**" folder and files that require create/write access are Installed under the **LocalAppData** folder ("**C:\Users\bLight\AppData\Local**" when calling the "**SHGetKnownFolderPath**" WinAPI function with the **FOLDERID_LocalAppData** parameter).

My problem is the AppX file created by *Desktop Bridge* installs the files the installer targeted for installation to "FOLDERID_LocalAppData" (**C:\Users\bLight\AppData\Local\Zoom Player**) here:

**C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ZoomPlayer_12.5.0.0_x86__63ghcm0aqanjp\VFS\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Zoom Player**

And any subsequent read or write attempts after running the installed App are redirected to :

**c:\users\bLight\appdata\local\packages\zoomplayer_63ghcm0aqanjp\LocalCache\Local\Zoom Player**

This means the installed files can not be accessed.

Both the installer and the Win32 app use "SHGetKnownFolderPath" with the same parameters to retrieve the Local AppData folder.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how I can resolve this?

After conversion, AppData is redirected to the local app data store, which is a private store for each UWP app.

Please notice this scenario: **Your app writes to the install directory for your app**. For example, your app writes to a log file that you put in the same directory as your exe. **This isn't supported**, so you'll need to find another location, like the local app data store.

See **Prepare your desktop app for conversion to UWP** section in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

----------------Update 1----------------

[Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068779/rob-caplan-msft) has provided the right direction in your [MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/284bfaec-392a-4775-864f-225543ca9b86)

Quote:

> Is it impossible for the AppX installer to automatically place some files into the local app data folder?

*Yes. The recommended pattern is to include the template files in the install package and then copy them to the local app data folder on first use.
When an app package is installed it's just copied into the system. It doesn't run any initialization code. It doesn't know which users will run the app and doesn't have access to their user data. If a second user installs the app then the user gets a reference to the already-installed app and nothing new is copied or installed.*

> A normal Win32 installer doesn't only place files into the "Program Files" folder, it places editable files into the "Local AppData" folder

This seems a problem scenario, we will notice the related team to check it and refine the document.

Comment: This is not the issue, the AppX is not writing files destined for local app data store.  The Win32 installer tries to write some files there by getting the local app data path by calling the WinAPI SHGetKnownFolderPath with the FOLDERID_LocalAppData parameter, but after conversion with Desktop Bridge, the AppX installer places the files in an unreachable folder.

Comment: @bLight Please see my update. Thank you for pointing it out:)