# Calling ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path in WPF throws exception

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a WPF application which I am porting to UWP via desktop bridge. In my WPF Application I am accessing UWP API to get package file path:

`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`

But calling this API it's throwing exception as below:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,

I have package manifest with proper package ID, but still not sure why I am getting this exception.

Comment: Try using string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

Comment: Thanks, but that will provide local path and not the package path where the App(UWP) is installed.

Comment: Did you read this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/06/23/accessing-to-the-files-in-the-installation-folder-in-a-desktop-bridge-application/

Comment: @mm8 The link that you mentioned refers to WinForms instead of WPF.

Comment: WPF is Win32. The blog post uses a real example with a "very simple Windows Forms app". Maybe you should try to read it.

Comment: Yeah, I gone through the article but as mentioned in my post that I want to save data in app local storage. You can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39449756/3244198) answer in which it is stated that as the correct way to store data. ("This isn't supported, so you'll need to find another location, like the local app data store.")

Comment: I am able to access UWP `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` but not actually able to use it so also want to know that whether it is supported for desktop bridge or not as there's no clear documentation of it on MSDN.

Comment: @Dishant The `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` returns a path string value. What did you want to do by using this path string value?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I want to pass that path to Data Layer, which is responsible of creating a database at the specified path.

Comment: @Dishant You'd better use [CreateFileAsync(String, CreationCollisionOption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfileasync#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_CreateFileAsync_System_String_Windows_Storage_CreationCollisionOption_) method of LocalFolder to create file instead of the path.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Actually I created new WPF project and added reference to UWP packagin project and was able to use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` as expected. Will further have a look on why it's not working with my current project.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT  `var file = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;` line throws exception while running the project. If I comment out that line it's working as expected. Same for `CreateFileAsync`

Answer (score 0):

@Dishant There're two things to note here:

ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path is not actually the path to the package install directory.

Writing to the package install directory is not allowed. It’s one of the things called in the [packaging guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).

Comment: But right now while debugging I am able to create file and can also write to it. Is it that something that it will stop working after I submit it to the windows store.

Comment: @Dishant Did you mean that you could create and write file in package install directory?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am able to write in the LocalState folder which is in the App Package folder

Comment: @Dishant The LocalState folder is not the package install directory.